# Why Xdebug install fails in php 5.6 Dockerfile?

Tags: php, docker, debugging, xdebug

I'm new to Docker, and got a project to maintain which developed with php 5.6.

I need to add xdebug to the container for debugging with VSCODE.

This is my Dockerfile

```
FROM test/php56:latest

RUN curl -sL https://rpm.nodesource.com/setup_11.x | bash -\
    && yum install -y nodejs zip \
    && yum clean all

RUN npm install -g gulp-cli

#The following line is added by me
RUN pecl install xdebug && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug

VOLUME ["/etc/httpd/vhost.d", "/var/www/html", "/etc/httpd/ssl"]

EXPOSE 80 443

#COPY run.sh /run.sh

#CMD ["/run.sh"]
```

when I run;

```
docker compose up -d --build
```

I get;

```
    ERROR [4/4] RUN pecl install xdebug-2.2.0 && docker-php-ext-enable 

xdebug                                                                                                                         4.9s
------                                                                                                                                                                                                     
 > [4/4] RUN pecl install xdebug-2.2.0 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug:                                                                                                                                    
#0 3.113 WARNING: channel "pecl.php.net" has updated its protocols, use "pecl channel-update pecl.php.net" to update                                                                                       
#0 3.713 downloading xdebug-2.2.0.tgz ...                                                                                                                                                                  
#0 3.714 Starting to download xdebug-2.2.0.tgz (247,670 bytes)                                                                                                                                             
#0 3.714 ...........................done: 247,670 bytes                                                                                                                                                    
#0 4.822 66 source files, building
#0 4.822 running: phpize
#0 4.828 Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
#0 4.828 The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
#0 4.829 ERROR: `phpize' failed
------
failed to solve: executor failed running [/bin/sh -c pecl install xdebug-2.2.0 && docker-php-ext-enable xdebug]: exit code: 1
```

I tried different versions of Xdebug, but not succeed.

Can anyone please point me in the right direction to solve the issue?

Comment: "The php-devel package is required for use of this command". 5.6 has been unsupported for four years now (https://www.php.net/eol.php) so expect potential trouble getting things working.

Comment: Keep in mind that PHP 5.6 is horribly outdated (EOL since 2018), as is XDebug 2.2.0 (released in 2012!). You should start updating your application before it gets hacked by any unclosed security hole

Answer (score 1):

It says so right here in the error message:

```
#0 4.828 Can't find PHP headers in /usr/include/php
#0 4.828 The php-devel package is required for use of this command.
```